# Add 'Top product' field to products Ubercart

Tags: views, nodes, ubercart

I'm trying to filter products on the homepage of my webshop (Views module). I want to add small ribbons to my products like: New,Top,Sale.

I made everything with the Views module but I think need to add a field to the Product content type but don't know what I need to choose, if I edit the product there should be a checkbox so I can edit if this product is New,Top,Sale or not.

Answer (score 0):

The default product and all product classes are a node content type that can have fields added to it. Go to **Structure > Content types > Product > Manage fields** to add your checkbox fields. The field will then be available in any node view for display or filtering.